# Why are some shortcuts modified with the Shift key while others are modified with the Option key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I have used Windows for all of my life. In Windows, shortcuts are (almost) always initiated with the <kbd>Control</kbd> key. Modifications to those shortcuts are then done with the <kbd>⇧</kbd> key. So, for example, you move to the next tab using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> and move to the previous tab using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>.

I have recently moved to OS X and I'm having a hard time remembering when to use <kbd>⌥</kbd> and when to use <kbd>⇧</kbd> in combination with <kbd>⌘</kbd>. I almost never get it right. It is like it is random, but I want to think there is actually a rule.

So, does this rule actually exist?

Comment: maybe you can look it up here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: Tab switching can actually be done any of 3 ways - ctrl (shift) tab; cmd shift left-right arrow; or cmd shift [ or ]

Comment: @Buscar웃, I was actually asking for the philosophy behind it.

Comment: I do not know the philosophy behind it on OS X, would you mind explaining it for Windows!

Comment: @Buscar웃 I already did? Windows uses ⇧ to modify shortcuts only.

Answer (score 1):

Well, coming from a Windows background myself, I can state the following:

1. The **Cmd** key is usually like **Ctrl** on Windows (e.g., **Ctrl+c** == **Cmd+c**).
2. As with Windows, the **Shift** key is a common modifier to the **Cmd** key.
3. I believe that Macs traditionally had an **Option** key, which also came to be known as the **Alt** key (perhaps to help those accustomed to Windows).
4. Aside from that, both **Ctrl** and **Option** are treated like modifiers on the **Cmd** key.

Between different Mac applications, there is sorta an effort to have some consistency in what certain key combinations do. For example, **Ctrl+Cmd+f** is usually a full-screen toggle.

However, the consistency of such keyboard shortcuts can vary per the software publisher.

Now, as a person that is familiar with Windows, you'll notice that **Alt** doesn't activate a menu mode, such as being able to drill down to a specific menu item.

However,you can create a keyboard shortcut via **System Preferences** >> **Keyboard** >> **Shortcuts** >> **App Shortcuts**. Just type the shortcut name as it appears in the application's menu.